# measurements for punch like 1/8 of 12 fluid ounces

Tags: measurements

I need to know how much is 1/8 of frozen orange juice, when it is out of 12 fluid ounce  and also 1/8th of 15.25 ounce of fruit cocktail..

Comment: Not clear what is the question here ? 1/8 of frozen juice again 12 ounces of what ? Do you have a set recipe for your punch?

Comment: Are you asking how to do the math (1/8 of 12 oz.) or how to put together the parts (fractions) of a recipe? Please clarify. Adding the recipe and what you're trying to accomplish would be a huge help. E.g., are you trying to make 1/8 of a recipe?

Answer (score 3):

If the punch recipe is 1/8 frozen juice, 1/8 fruit cocktail etc. then this is to make scaling easier. You'd use equal quantities of all ingredients that are each 1/8, and twice as much of anything that says 1/4

Example: If you wanted to use a whole 12 fl. oz container of juice, you'd need 12fl. oz of fruit cocktail, so you'd have a bit left over. You'd make 8x12=96fl. oz in total . If you wanted to use the whole container of fruit cocktail, you'd need to open a second container of juice. In this sort of recipe though, the difference between 12oz and 15oz is minimal, so you could easily use the whole container of both.

Answer (score -1):

1/8 of 12 oz is 1.5 ounces.  1/8 of 15.25 oz is 1.9 ounces.  You can easily look this up on google.